# Is it possible to Alter Tomcat Web Application Manager's Theme or Modify its Header?

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, themes

I have couple instances of tomcat server sitting on my computer (one's production and one is staging/test/training).

The (example) url for the tomcat web app mgr for both production and test is as such:

`Production: xWeb8.myOwnServer/manager/html`

`test:       xWeb8Test.myOwnServer/manager/html`

I was wondering if it is possible to access the Tomcat Web Application Manager and modify its display and/or add a color theme to indicate if it is production or test, etc.? If yes, how can this be done?

Comment: yes you can go to `webapps/manager` and play with the styling code of the application. All the files are there and you can change any styling.

Comment: @SuKu see my answer below. The index.jsp file just redirects you to the `/html` servlet, and all the presentation is found in that servlet.

Answer (score 3):

In your `webapps` directory you will find the `manager` directory. Looking at the `index.jsp`,  `web.xml`, and the source code to the `HTMLManagerServlet`, it looks like it is all hard-coded into the servlet. So it looks like it is not easily possible without rewriting the whole thing.

*Update*: You can create a Filter that modifies the HTML as it passes through the filter.

Answer (score 2):

Although this is an old post, I thought I'd give my 2 cents ...

It seems even with later versions on Tomcat we cannot actually alter the look of the Manager.

However, what I did was replace the "tomcat.gif" in the "../manager/images" folder with a modified gif that identifies  which system I am connected to.

See this screen print of the image I use ...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at that myself and after I found this post I came up with the following idea:

1. Create a simple .html page with some java script that can detect onLoad events in another window/tab.
2. Open the manager page. When it loads your custom page will detect the onLoad event and using the DOM will make the necessary modifications on the fly - change CSS, add  elements, etc.

I know this is a bit indirect but it will work.

Comment: This would not work. It is generally not possible to attach events to or access the DOM of other windows. However, this idea could be implemented as a browser extension.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css to change the theme per page

e.g. https://userstyles.org/styles/153943/tomcat-8-manager-dark

```
/* Tomcat Dark Theme - Jerome E. Carter, II - Datatribe Softwers, Ltd. cc 2018 */

body, table
{
  background-color: #555555!important;
}

button, input
{
  background-color: #333333!important;
  border: 1px solid white!important;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #ffaa00;
}

/*not working as intended - hope to improve later*/
input[type=button]:hover
{
  background-color: #777777;
}

td
{
  background-color: #777777!important;
}

*
{
  color: white;
}

a
{
  color: #ffaa00;
}

tr:hover
{
  border-color: #aaaaaa!important;
}
```

The easiest way to do this is via a browser extension

e.g.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/styl-us/?src=search

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylus/clngdbkpkpeebahjckkjfobafhncgmne